# Change color of standard salesforce images samples

Tags: formula, fields

I would like to know if it is possible to change the color of this type of image /img/samples/color_yellow.gif
I would like to use other colors, such as blue or orange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, formula fields cannot do that.

Further, Apex can't really do that either. GIF is a relatively simple image format, and you could likely change part of the palette table, but Apex doesn't have bit/byte types (which is really what we would need to do this type of manipulation ourselves).

If you need additional colors, you should upload additional static resources.